# Python 3.5 builtins.keyerror:'A'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I'm newer to Python and don't understand what is causing this error. OS-Mavericks wingware ide

I'm getting the error on **sum_mp=sum(float(d_pr_matrix[pl][j]) for j,pl in enumerate(p))**

# read input
    in_file = open('input.txt', 'r')

```
line = 1
in_kmer = 0
in_dna=''
in_profile=[]
in_matrix=[]
ldata = ''
m=0
for in_data in in_file:
    ldata = in_data.strip(' \t\n\r')
    if (line==1):
        in_dna = ldata
    elif (line==2):
        in_kmer=int(ldata)
    elif (line==3):
        in_profile=ldata.split()    
    elif (line>1 and len(ldata)!=0):
        m+=1
        in_matrix.append(ldata)
    line+=1

 d_pr_matrix = {}
for i,p in enumerate(in_profile):
    pm=[]
    for j in range(0,m):
         pm.append((in_matrix[j].split())[i])
    d_pr_matrix[p]=pm

 max_mp=0
 max_dna=''
    for i in range(0, len(in_dna)-in_kmer+1):
     p = in_dna[i:i+in_kmer]
     sum_mp=sum(float(d_pr_matrix[pl][j]) for j,pl in enumerate(p))
     if(sum_mp> max_mp):
        max_mp = sum_mp
        max_dna = p

 print(max_mp,   max_dna)
```

'''
This is the input.txt 
'''

> ACCTGTTTATTGCCTAAGTTCCGAACAAACCCAATATAGCCCGAGGGCCT
>
> 5
>
> 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3
>
> 0.4 0.3 0.1 0.5 0.1
>
> 0.3 0.3 0.5 0.2 0.4
>
> 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2

What causes the error?

Comment: You don't have `A` as a key in `d_pr_matrix`. Do a `print(d_pr_matrix)` and see what it contains.

Comment: @JulienBernu Line 35 ' line 35, in <genexpr>
  sum_mp=sum(float(d_pr_matrix[pl][j]) for j,pl in enumerate(p))

builtins.KeyError: 'A''

Comment: What do you expect `d_pr_matrix` to contain?